# Understanding Oracle aliasing - why isn't an alias not recognized in a query unless wrapped in a second query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, alias

I have a query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "CNT",
       imei
FROM   devices
```

which executes just fine. I want to further restrict the query with a WHERE statement. The (humanly) logical next step is to modify the query followingly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "CNT",
       imei
FROM   devices
WHERE  CNT > 1
```

However, this results in a error message **ORA-00904: "CNT": invalid identifier**. For some reason, wrapping the query in another query produces the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "CNT",
               imei
        FROM   devices
        GROUP  BY imei)
WHERE  CNT > 1
```

Why does Oracle not recognize the alias "CNT" in the second query?

Comment: As a sidenote: this query (with aggregates) is better written with the HAVING clause: "select count(\*) cnt, imei from devices group by imei having count(\*) > 1"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer is that the `AS` clause defines what the column will be called in the result, which is a different scope than the query itself.

In your example, using the `HAVING` clause would work best:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "CNT",
       imei
FROM   devices
GROUP  BY imei
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: In the OP's question, it's not just that HAVING would work best, it's that HAVING is the answer. You can't apply a where clause to an aggregate like count(*), which is why the HAVING clause exists. Also, as per standard SQL order of processing, WHERE happens before the SELECT, so the alias CNT doesn't even exist at the point in time when the WHERE clause is applied. From, Where, Group By, Having, Select Order By http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

Answer (score 14):

Because the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) says it won't:

> Specify an alias for the column
>   expression. Oracle Database will use
>   this alias in the column heading of
>   the result set. The AS keyword is
>   optional. The alias effectively
>   renames the select list item for the
>   duration of the query. The alias can
>   be used in the order_by_clause but not
>   other clauses in the query.

However, when you have an inner select, that is like creating an inline view where the column aliases take effect, so you are able to use that in the outer level.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize, this little gem explains:

[10 Easy Steps to a Complete Understanding of SQL](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1555/10-easy-steps-to-a-complete-understanding-of-sql)

> A common source of confusion is the simple fact that SQL syntax
>   elements are not ordered in the way they are executed. The lexical
>   ordering is:
>
> ```
> SELECT [ DISTINCT ]
> FROM
> WHERE
> GROUP BY
> HAVING
> UNION
> ORDER BY
> ```
>
> For simplicity, not all SQL clauses are listed. This lexical ordering
>   differs fundamentally from the logical order, i.e. from the order of
>   execution:
>
> ```
> FROM
> WHERE
> GROUP BY
> HAVING
> SELECT
> DISTINCT
> UNION
> ORDER BY
> ```

As a consequence, anything that you label using "AS" will only be available once the `WHERE`, `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` have already been performed.

Answer (score 4):

I would imagine because the alias is not assigned to the result column until after the WHERE clause has been processed and the data generated.  Is Oracle different from other DBMSs in this behaviour?