# ORA-00904 "Invalid identifier” for an identifier in a group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors

with compiere database i am trying ro show

between two dates.

column:

designation

qty sale (depot) client sales

qty-sale sellers selling deliveryman

-total qty

value turnover by product

why is this query

```
SELECT p.name AS design,
  p.M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID,
  il.PRICEACTUAL   AS price,
  bp.C_BPARTNER_ID AS idpartner,
  CASE
    WHEN i.IsReturnTrx = 'N'
    THEN SUM(il.linenetamt)
    ELSE SUM(il.linenetamt)*-1
  END AS netHT,
  CASE
    WHEN i.IsReturnTrx = 'N'
    THEN SUM((il.linenetamt + (il.linenetamt * t.rate /100)))
    ELSE SUM((il.linenetamt + (il.linenetamt * t.rate /100)))*-1
  END AS netTTC,
  (SELECT il.qtyinvoiced
  FROM C_InvoiceLine il
  WHERE bp.ISCUSTOMER ='Y'
  AND bp.ISACTIVE     ='Y'
  AND bp.C_BPARTNER_ID= 19999
  )              AS qtydepot,
  (SELECT qtyinvoiced
  FROM C_InvoiceLine il
  WHERE bp.ISCUSTOMER ='Y'
  AND bp.C_BPARTNER_ID= 18888
  )               AS qtyliv,
  org.description AS orgname,
  loc2.address1,
  loc2.address2,
  loc2.address3,
  loc2.address4,
  loc2.city,
  loc2.postal,
  oi.phone,
  oi.phone2,
  oi.fax,
  i.DATEINVOICED AS dat
FROM C_InvoiceLine il
INNER JOIN M_PRODUCT p
ON(p.M_PRODUCT_ID = il.M_PRODUCT_ID)
INNER JOIN C_INVOICE i
ON (i.C_INVOICE_ID = il.C_INVOICE_ID)
INNER JOIN C_BPARTNER bp
ON (bp.C_BPARTNER_ID = i.C_BPARTNER_ID)
INNER JOIN AD_Org org
ON (i.AD_Org_ID = org.AD_Org_ID)
INNER JOIN C_Tax t
ON (t.C_Tax_ID = il.C_Tax_ID)
INNER JOIN ad_orginfo oi
ON (org.ad_org_id=oi.ad_org_id)
INNER JOIN c_location loc2
ON (oi.c_location_id=loc2.c_location_id)
  --WHERE i.DateInvoiced BETWEEN $P{Date1} AND $P{Date2}
  --AND
  --i.DocStatus in ('CO','CL')
  --AND i.IsSoTrx = 'Y'
  --AND   p.isstocked='Y'
GROUP BY p.name ,
  p.M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID,
  il.QTYINVOICED,
  il.PRICEACTUAL,
  i.DATEINVOICED,
  bp.C_BPARTNER_ID,
  org.description,
  loc2.address1,
  loc2.address2,
  loc2.address3,
  loc2.address4,
  loc2.city,
  loc2.postal,
  oi.phone,
  oi.phone2,
  oi.fax,
  i.IsReturnTrx,
  i.dateinvoiced,
  qtyliv,
  qtydepot
ORDER BY p.name ,
  i.dateinvoiced ;
```

giving me this error:

```
ORA-00904: "QTYLIV" : identificateur non valide
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erreur à la ligne 75, colonne 3
```

Comment: Can you try to minimize the SQL, so  you can see where the error comes from?

Comment: probleme is here (SELECT il.qtyinvoiced
  FROM C_InvoiceLine il
  WHERE bp.ISCUSTOMER ='Y'
  AND bp.ISACTIVE     ='Y'
  AND bp.C_BPARTNER_ID= 19999
  )              AS qtydepot,
  (SELECT qtyinvoiced
  FROM C_InvoiceLine il
  WHERE bp.ISCUSTOMER ='Y'
  AND bp.C_BPARTNER_ID= 18888
  )               AS qtyliv,

Comment: The error is reported on line 75, which is when you refer to `qtyliv` in the `GROUP BY`, not in that subquery itself.

Comment: i cant do it Mat if you can edit code and give it to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Oracle aliasing - why isn't an alias not recognized in a query unless wrapped in a second query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153778/understanding-oracle-aliasing-why-isnt-an-alias-not-recognized-in-a-query-unl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same level of SQL, except in the `order by` clause.

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries002.htm#sthref2213) (emphasis added):

> You can use a column alias, *c_alias*, to label the immediately preceding expression in the select list so that the column is displayed with a new heading. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. **The alias can be used in the  `ORDER BY` clause, but not other clauses in the query**.

When you refer to `QTYLIV` in the `GROUP BY` cluase the select list hasn't been evaluated yet and the alias doesn't exist. This is just how the query is parsed and executed.

When you have complicated expressions in the select list it's often simplest to wrap that in an outer select and do the grouping afterwards:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT p.name AS design,
    p.M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID,
    il.PRICEACTUAL   AS price,
    bp.C_BPARTNER_ID AS idpartner,
    CASE
  ...
    (SELECT qtyinvoiced
    FROM C_InvoiceLine il
    WHERE bp.ISCUSTOMER ='Y'
    AND bp.C_BPARTNER_ID= 18888
    )               AS qtyliv,
  ...
    i.DATEINVOICED AS dat
  FROM C_InvoiceLine il
  INNER JOIN M_PRODUCT p
  ...
  ON (oi.c_location_id=loc2.c_location_id)
    --WHERE i.DateInvoiced BETWEEN $P{Date1} AND $P{Date2}
    --AND
    --i.DocStatus in ('CO','CL')
    --AND i.IsSoTrx = 'Y'
    --AND   p.isstocked='Y'
)
GROUP BY name ,
  M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID,
  QTYINVOICED,
  PRICEACTUAL,
...
  qtyliv,
  qtydepot
ORDER BY name ,
  dateinvoiced ;
```

Notice that you don't use the original table aliases in the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clauses in the outer select, as those are no longer in scope.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is (at least) in the `group by` clause.  Oracle does not allow column aliases in `group by`.  You can readily fix this with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select . . .
      from . . .
      where . . .
     ) t
group by . . . 
order by . . . ;
```

In other words, put everything but the `group by` and `order by` in a subquery.  Then put those clauses in the outer query.

Comment: you mean that
  (SELECT il.qtyinvoiced
  FROM C_InvoiceLine il
  WHERE bp.ISCUSTOMER ='Y'
  AND bp.C_BPARTNER_ID= 18888
  group by il.qtyinvoiced
  )               AS qtyliv,

Comment: @mugiwaradz . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  The `as qtyliv` defines a column alias (called `qtyliv`).  You cannot use this in the `group by` clause directly.  So, put your original query, minus the `group by` and `order by` into a subquery.  And then put those clauses in the outer query.