# LINQ query to merge multiple rows

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I am trying to convert an SQL query that works, to LINQ equivalent.
Here is the query.

```
SELECT REPORT_NUMBER, 
case when count(distinct STATE) > 1 then 'PENDING' 
    else case when  max(STATE) = 'REPORTED' then 'REPORTED' 
else 'PENDING' end end status, 
max(REPORT_YEAR) 
FROM SAMPLE 
GROUP BY REPORT_NUMBER 
ORDER BY max(REPORT_YEAR) DESC
```

So far I created LINQ query that needed a help.

```
var sums = from foo in db.SAMPLEs
           group foo by foo.REPORT_NUMBER into groupings
           orderby groupings.Key ascending
           select new ReportListModel
           {
               ReportNbr = groupings.Key,
               ReportYear = groupings.Max(g => g.REPORT_YEAR),
               ReportSt = groupings.Max(g => g.STATE)
            };
```

Using `groupings.Max(g => g.STATE)` gives me correct amount of records, but obviously gives me incorrect field result.

How can I create case statement as in SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inline-if operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) like so:

```
var sums = from foo in db.SAMPLEs
           group foo by foo.REPORT_NUMBER into groupings
           orderby groupings.Key ascending
           select new ReportListModel
           {
               ReportNbr = groupings.Key,
               ReportStatus = 
                groupings.Select(x => x.STATE).Distinct().Count() > 1 ? 
                    "PENDING" : (
                        groupings.Max(g => g.STATE) == "REPORTED" ?
                            "REPORTED" : "PENDING"
                    )
            };
```

Comment: ReportStatus logic might not be 100% correct, but this is what I inferred from your SQL, if you could form that logic in words it might me helpful.

Comment: The logic is that there are multiple records with one report number. If all records have status REPORTED than the row should indicate status REPORTED. If at list on record is not REPORTED than group record must be PENDING. I checked your suggestion. It gives me an error 'InnerException = {"ORA-00904: \"GroupBy1\".\"K1\": invalid identifier"}'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @yrluc seems something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980245/ora-00904-invalid-identifier-for-an-identifier-in-a-group-by-clause (will have a look again tomorrow..)

Comment: In order to use inline statement I had to divide query on two. First part to get data and second set is to further to group it to set STATE as I needed to be. Is there any way to combine two LINQ queries?