# sql query to merge data from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query (for Oracle). I have three tables:

```
sale
====================================
sale_id | part_id | amt | cost | qty

quote
==============================
quote_id | part_id | amt | qty

part
================
part_id | number
```

And I need to write a query that groups the numbers by part number similar to this (non-functional) query:

```
select p.number 

sum(s.amt * s.qty) as sales_amt_total,
sum(s.qty) as sales_qty_total,
count(s.sale_id) as sales_count,
sum(s.qty * s.cost) as cost_total,

sum(q.amt * q.qty) as quotes_amt_total,
sum(q.qty) as quotes_qty_total,
count(q.quote_id) as quotes_count

from parts p
inner join quotes q on q.part_id = p.part_id
inner join sales s on s.part_id = p.part_id

group by p.number

having sales_amt_total < ?
and sales_amt_total > ?
and sales_qty_total < ?
and sales_qty_total > ?
and sales_count < ?
and sales_count > ?
and cost_total < ?
and cost_total > ?

and quotes_amt_total < ?
and quotes_amt_total > ?
and quotes_qty_total < ?
and quotes_qty_total > ?
and quotes_count < ?
and quotes_count > ?

;
```

producing a result like this:

```
number | sales_amt_total | sales_qty_total | sales_count | cost_total | ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    P1 |         9999999 |         9999999 |     9999999 |    9999999 | ...
    P2 |         9999999 |         9999999 |     9999999 |    9999999 | ...
    P3 |         9999999 |         9999999 |     9999999 |    9999999 | ...
```

However, the `inner join quotes` and `inner join sales` creates inflated numbers because it's calculating for each match each time.

I could split these into two queries:

```
select p.number 

sum(s.amt * s.qty) as sales_amt_total,
sum(s.qty) as sales_qty_total,
count(s.sale_id) as sales_count,
sum(s.qty * s.cost) as cost_total,

from parts p
inner join sales s on s.part_id = p.part_id

having sales_amt_total < ?
and sales_amt_total > ?
and sales_qty_total < ?
and sales_qty_total > ?
and sales_count < ?
and sales_count > ?
and cost_total < ?
and cost_total > ?
;

select p.number 

sum(q.amt * q.qty) as quotes_amt_total,
sum(q.qty) as quotes_qty_total,
count(q.quote_id) as quotes_count

from parts p
inner join quotes q on q.part_id = p.part_id

group by p.number

having quotes_amt_total < ?
and quotes_amt_total > ?
and quotes_qty_total < ?
and quotes_qty_total > ?
and quotes_count < ?
and quotes_count > ?

;
```

But I lose the ability to apply the `having` clauses to each table.

How would you create this query?

Comment: Showing us non functional queries actually does not do very much to get your point across.  Instead, please show us sample table data along with the expected output.

Comment: Well if I could get it to function I wouldn't be asking the question

Comment: Sample output is in the question

Comment: If you can't articulate input and output data, then either you don't understand your own question, or you haven't thought about it enough yet to post.

Comment: Just consider it pseudocode that is meant to convey functionality without the need for overexplanation

Comment: `creates inflated numbers` ... I actually know how to fix this.  You just need to perform the aggregations in separate subqueries, and then join to those subqueries.

Comment: "I actually know how to fix this" ok can you help create aggregate subqueries and answer the question? I tried subqueries but I wasn't able to get it to work

Comment: May I ask what is your intention with the logic in the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: Because `where` won't work with aggregate functions and alias' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153778/understanding-oracle-aliasing-why-isnt-an-alias-not-recognized-in-a-query-unl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
WITH ctePART_QUOTES AS
       (SELECT qq.PART_ID,
               COUNT(*) AS QUOTES_COUNT
               SUM(qq.AMT * qq.QTY) AS QUOTES_AMT_TOTAL,
               SUM(qq.QTY) as QUOTES_QTY_TOTAL
          FROM QUOTES qq
          GROUP BY qq.PART_ID),
     ctePART_SALES AS
       (SELECT ss.PART_ID,
               COUNT(*) AS SALES_COUNT,
               SUM(ss.AMT * ss.QTY) AS SALES_AMT_TOTAL,
               SUM(ss.QTY) AS SALES_QTY_TOTAL,
               COUNT(*) AS SALES_COUNT,
               SUM(ss.QTY * ss.COST) AS COST_TOTAL
          FROM SALES ss
          GROUP BY ss.PART_ID)
SELECT p.NUMBER,
       s.SALES_AMT_TOTAL,
       s.SALES_QTY_TOTAL,
       s.SALES_COUNT,
       s.COST_TOTAL,
       q.QUOTES_AMT_TOTAL,
       q.QUOTES_QTY_TOTAL,
       q.QUOTES_COUNT
  FROM PARTS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePART_QUOTES q
    ON q.PART_ID = p.PART_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePART_SALES s
    ON s.PART_ID = p.PART_ID
```

Add all your `HAVING` stuff and you should be good to go.

Best of luck.