# Oracle [Error] Execution (31: 5): ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I have written the following query

```
SELECT TPD.*, 
   FMP.*
   FROM TABLE TPD
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT *
FROM TBL FMP
WHERE FMP.FE6_MILEPOST_SEQ_I = 0)
ON FMP.FE6_MILEPOST_I = TPD.CURR_STATION_MP_I
```

The two sub queries inside works separately but when joined, it throws the following error

[Error] Execution (31: 5): ORA-00904: "FMP"."FE6_MILEPOST_I": invalid identifier

Comment: Give you sub-query an `alias` and then use it in a `JOIN`.

Comment: This is (clearly) a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Oracle aliasing - why isn't an alias not recognized in a query unless wrapped in a second query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153778/understanding-oracle-aliasing-why-isnt-an-alias-not-recognized-in-a-query-unl)

Answer (score 0):

You have to alias your derived table, e.g. like this:

```sql
(SELECT FMP.FE6_MILEPOST_I,
   FMP.OPERATIONAL_REGION_C,
   FMP.OPERATIONAL_REGION_N,
   FMP.OPERATING_ZONE_C,
   FMP.OPERATING_ZONE_N,
   FMP.OPERATING_SUBDIVISION_C,
   FMP.OPERATING_SUBDIVISION_N
FROM TBL FMP
WHERE FMP.FE6_MILEPOST_SEQ_I = 0) FMP
```

The `FMP` alias that you gave your `TBL` *within* the derived table does not "escape" the derived table's nested namespacing scope. I.e. you cannot "see" that table name from outside. Without giving the derived table any name, you can only reference its projected columns without qualification.

Notice that Oracle is one of the few databases that actually allow you to skip aliasing derived tables in the first place, for quick and dirty querying. Even so, I recommend you *always* alias your derived tables, even in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs an alias, so you can refer to columns it returns in the outer query.

But here, I would suggest simplifying the `FROM` clause. Using a subquery does not see useful anyway, so you could just go:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE TPD
LEFT JOIN TBL FMP
    ON  FMP.FE6_MILEPOST_SEQ_I = 0
    AND FMP.FE6_MILEPOST_I = TPD.CURR_STATION_MP_I
```